# paste column elements with condition in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame and I want to paste elements in `name1`, `name2` and `name3` which do not contain `NA`.

```
c <- data.frame(name1 = letters[1:3],
                name2 = c('A', NA, 'C'),
                name3 = c('pig', 'cow', NA)
                )
```

The result should like this:

```
c %>% mutate(new_name = c('a&A&pig', 'b&cow', 'c&C'))
```

When I use `paste0()` it binds all the elements including `NA`. I do not want this.

```
c %>% mutate(new_name = paste0(name1,'&', name2, '&', name3))
```

Then I tried another two method. One is split the data frame into list with `group_split()`, the other is nest the data frame by `index`. And then use `map()` and `select()` to select the column that do not contain `NA` after the two methods but all failed.

```
 c %>% 
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
  group_split(index) %>% 
  map(select(~where(~!any(is.na(.)))))

c %>% 
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
  nest(data = name1:name3) %>% 
  mutate(without_NA_data = map(data, select(~where(~!any(is.na(.))))))
```

Is there any way I can get what I want?
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowwise` with `c_across` by loading only `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)    
c %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(new_name = paste(na.omit(c_across(everything())), collapse="&")) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# name1 name2 name3 new_name
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   
#1 a     A     pig   a&A&pig 
#2 b     <NA>  cow   b&cow   
#3 c     C     <NA>  c&C
```

---

Or with `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
c %>% 
     mutate(new_name = pmap_chr(., ~ paste(na.omit(c(...)), collapse="&")))
#  name1 name2 name3 new_name
#1     a     A   pig  a&A&pig
#2     b  <NA>   cow    b&cow
#3     c     C  <NA>      c&C
```

---

Or using `base R` with `paste` and `replace`

```
trimws(do.call(paste, c(replace(c, is.na(c), ''), sep="&")), whitespace = "&")
#[1] "a&A&pig" "b&&cow"  "c&C"
```

---

Or using `apply`

```
apply(c, 1, function(x)  paste(na.omit(x), collapse="&"))
#[1] "a&A&pig" "b&cow"   "c&C"
```

---

Or `paste` first and remove the `NA` substring

```
gsub("&NA|NA&|NA$", "", do.call(paste, c(c, sep="&")))
#[1] "a&A&pig" "b&cow"   "c&C"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unite` from `tidyr` by using `na.rm = TRUE` to remove `NA` values

```
tidyr::unite(c, new_name, starts_with('name'), 
                sep = '&', na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE)

#  new_name name1 name2 name3
#1  a&A&pig     a     A   pig
#2    b&cow     b  <NA>   cow
#3      c&C     c     C  <NA>
```